# PDF doc in Iframe not displaying in IE9 - IE9 asks to open or save only

Tags: pdf, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I have a pdf file that is called inside an iframe. I call the full absolute path of the pdf in the iframe. It displays correctly in all browsers. Except in IE9. IE 9 just asks if you want to open or save the PDF. Then after you open or save it, a blank white space appears inside iframe.

Please help if you have any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could provide some example code?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the added twist that it works fine on my live system but not on my staging instance.